# can access my sql without using password but cannot access with password

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I create a new mysql user by using

```
CREATE USER 'new-username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-password'; 
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'new-username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And I can access mysql by

```
 mysql -u new-username
```

But I got this error message when I try to access mysql using password

```
mysql -u new-username -p
```

error message

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'new-username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Something I am missing? Mysql version is  Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem...... What's happening here?

Answer (score -1):

Here you required to pass password but you dont have entered any password.

```
CREATE USER 'new-username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-password'; 
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'new-username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql -u new-username -p new-password
```

And if you want to remove password from that then just use following line

```
SET PASSWORD FOR  'new-username'@'localhost' =  ''
```